# Will MSBuild support .Net Core Projects

Tags: msbuild, .net-core

I've been researching for a while now. Unfortunately all sources I read are outdated. Anyone knows if MSBuild plans to support .Net Core Applicatoins?

And is there a other Build Engine which Supports it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use dotnet CLI for building .Net Core projects and its dependencies using msbuild.
Use following command to build .Net Core project/solutions.

```
dotnet msbuild
```

The command has same capabilities as existing MSBuild command-line client.

Answer (score 0):

That does not help in case a .NET Core library is used in a non-Core project, e.g. UWP :-(